# Route Constraint breaks Authorize Attribute filter - MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-routing

After adding a routing constraint I noticed that when navigating to a URL which this routing constraint is applied, my application is no longer executing my authorize attribute filter.

**FilterConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

**ProjectsController.cs**

```
public class ProjectsController : Controller
{
    private IRepository<Project> repository;

    public ProjectsController()
    {
        repository = new Repository<Project>();
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Project project = repository.FindById(id);

        if (project == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        ProjectsEditViewModel projectVM = new ProjectsEditViewModel(project);

        return View("Edit", projectVM);
    }
}
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ProjectEdit",
            url: "Projects/Edit/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Projects", action = "Edit" },
            constraints: new { id = new IsValidProjectConstraint() }
        );
    }
}
```

**IsValidProjectConstraint.cs**

```
public class IsValidProjectConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        IRepository<Project> projectsRepository = new Repository<Project>();

        try
        {
            int iProjectId;
            Project project;

            // Check for valid id
            if (int.TryParse(values["id"].ToString(), out iProjectId))
            {
                project = projectsRepository.FindById(iProjectId);

                // Check if this project exists
                if (project == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

            // If we made it here everything is good
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Web.Config**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/SAML/saml2" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

After adding this routing constraint, navigating to `http://myurl/Projects/Edit/1` in a new browser will actually render the page as if I have already been authenticated. However, when removing the routing constraint and then navigating to `http://myurl/Projects/Edit/1` I am redirected to my login action as expected.

It seems that any route constraint, whether its my custom route constraint or simply a regular expression, is causing this issue.

Is there something that I am missing here??

**EDIT:**
I guess I should mention how I am issuing my FormsAuthentication cookie. My application acts as a SAML service provider, in which a SAML response from an identity provider is sent to my assertion consumer service. The acs parses the SAML response and validates it and then issues the authentication ticket via the following code:

```
private void IssueAuthTicket(User userData)
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket =
        new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userData.UserName,
            DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
            rememberMe, userData.Id.ToString());

    string ticketString = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

    HttpCookie cookie =
        new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, ticketString);

    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding the [Authorization] attribute above the controller or class you require authorization for?

Comment: Yes I've tried adding the AuthorizeAttribute to global filters, also tried adding [Authorize] attribute to the controller class itself, as well as adding it to the controller action itself. None seemed to make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that MVC will execute your routing constraints BEFORE your authorize attribute. The issue that I was facing here was that I had my routes defined as:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ProjectEdit",
        url: "Projects/Edit/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Projects", action = "Edit" },
        constraints: new { id = new IsValidProjectConstraint() }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "404-PageNotFound",
        url: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Errors", action = "NotFound" }
    );
}
```

so if the routing constraint `IsValidProjectConstraint()` returned false then action `NotFound` of controller `Errors` would execute. In this case it was always returning false because an error was caught when my `User` object was null. Unfortunately I had `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on my `Errors` controller which allowed for an error page to render, so it seemed as if MVC was not executing my `AuthorizeAttribute` filter.